# Url rewriting, raw url is omitting special characters

Tags: asp.net, url, url-rewriting

I am creating a site in asp.net with URL rewriting.

My initial url is like

> /mypage/languagename/ASP.NET

it is working fine when I am excepting taking the language name with

```
HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
app.Request.RawUrl // this is giving me ASP.NET
```

but when the initial URL is

> /mypage/languagename/C#

I am getting only C from the rawURL instead of C#.

How can I get the same?

Comment: the # character is not valid in urls. Try encoding your urls (# is `%23`, so you would get `/mypage/languagename/C%23`). Note [what StackOverflow does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) when you're searching for "C#"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [UrlDecoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx) becasue # is [URL Encoded Character](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode that url because it contains html special character, ie the #

Check this class, **System.Web.HttpServerUtility**. Use that class UrlEncode method to encode the url before using and it will solve your problem.